# Inserting 'n' blank rows using a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am currently trying to develop an excel spread sheet to make it easier to format. What I would like to do is create a macro to insert blank rows in multiple places without affecting subsequent rows. I am familiar with a little bit of coding. My psuedo code is as follows:

```
cell a1 = n
if(n>1, insert 'n' rows in row 10, insert '0' rows)
if(n>1, insert 'n' rows in row 20. insert '0' rows)
etc.
```

There may be a macro or function that already exists but i am not sure. If there isn't a macro available I would like to know how to create one.

Thanks

Comment: I answered based on a pretty standard way of doing this, but I'm unclear on what you mean by "without affecting subsequent rows"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
Sub test()
Dim n As Integer
n = Cells(1, 1)
    If n >= 1 Then
        Rows("10:" & 10 + n).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Rows("20:" & 20 + n).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
End Sub
```

You could also do it like this -

```
Sub test()
Dim n As Integer
n = Cells(1, 1)
    If n >= 1 Then
        For i = 1 To n
        Rows(10).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Rows(20).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```